# Show gallery separated by folders

Tags: android, directory, gallery

I want to acess gallery of an android device to get an photo, but I want that it shows the photos separeted by its folders.

I got a lot of examples, but all of them show the items in the same place.

A similar way that WhatsApp works when we want to pick a photo send.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with `photos separeted by its folders.` and `the same place` ?

Comment: SeparAted by folders: Show the directories that the photos are included. The same places: all photos together without a division by directory.

Comment: Then you are not accessing it in the right way.

Comment: I can see the photos, but not separated. Like the example here: [link] (http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

Comment: `Like the example`? You said  `I want to acess gallery`. Isn't it time now that you first explain what you are doing? In that blog example indeed all thumbnails are shown.